# `constexpr vector` still fails, while there's stated to be supported in cppreference

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support, `cosnstexpr vector` is stated to be supported.
[image]

But when I wrote

```cpp
#include <vector>

constexpr std::vector<int> vec{2, 3, 3, 3};
int main()
{
}
```

and compiles it using `-std=gnu++2b` flag,
it still triggers a error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/vector:61,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/allocator.h:182:50: error: ‘std::vector<int>(std::initializer_list<int>{((const int*)(& const int [4]{2, 3, 3, 3})), 4}, std::allocator<int>())’ is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of ‘operator new’
  182 |           return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why, can someone help me?

My gcc version `gcc version 12.1.0 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)`

and `__cpp_constexpr == 202110L`

Comment: You shouldn't inject an unrelated question into an existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` being `constexpr`-friendly means that it can be used inside a constant expression evaluation. It does not mean that a variable of that type can be declared with `constexpr` specifier. (Talking about `constexpr std::vector` in that context is maybe a bit misleading.)

Because `std::vector` uses dynamic allocation, it still must be destroyed during the evaluation of the constant expression, which is not the case in the initialization of a variable of that type.

What is allowed now is e.g.:

```
constexpr int some_calculation(int input) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    // some complicated algorithm using `input`, using `vec` to store e.g. intermediate results
    return /* the result */;
}

constexpr int constant_value = some_calculation(42);
```